# How to read caret notations from a binary file in C?

Tags: c, file-io, printf, concatenation, string-concatenation

I have a requirement to read the characters in a binary file one byte at a time and concatenate them when a certain condition is met. I'm running into problems while reading the null character i.e ^@ as denoted in the caret notations. Neither snprintf nor strcpy is helping me concatenate this null character with other characters. It is strange because when I print this character using

```
printf("%c",char1);
```

it prints out the null character in the caret notation i.e ^@. So my understanding is that even snprintf should have succeeded in concatenation.

Could anybody please let me know how can I achieve such a concatenation?

Thanks

Comment: BTW,  `printf("%c",char);` is not valid `C`. `char` is a reserved keyword. Do you mind showing us your actual code?

Comment: Sorry. I was just giving an example. Will change it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're not working with raw ANSI strings, you can't use functions meant to be used with raw ANSI strings, because the way the interpret strings.

In C (and C++) strings are usually null terminated, i.e. the last character is `\0` (value `0x00`). At least this is true for standard functions for string manipulation and input/ouput (like `printf()` or `strcpy()`).

For example, the line

```
const char *text = "Hello World";
```

behind the scenes becomes

```
const char *text = "Hello World\0";
```

So when you're reading `\0` from a file and putting it into your string, you essentially end up with an essentially empty string.

To make the issue more clear, just a simple example:

```
// Let's just assume the sequence 0x00, 0x01 is some special encoding
const char *input = "Hello\0\1World!";
char output[256];

strcpy(output, input);
// strncpy() is for string manipulation, as such it will stop once it encounters a null terminator

printf("%s\n", output); // This will print 'Hello'

memcpy(output, input, 14); // 14 is the string length above plus null terminator

printf("%s\n", output); // This will again print 'Hello' (since it stops at the terminator)

printf("%s\n", output + 7); // This will print "World" (you're skipping the terminator using the offset)
```

---

The following is a quick example I put together. It doesn't necessarily show best practice and it's also likely that there are a few bugs in there, but it should show you some possible concepts how to work with raw byte data, avoiding standard string functions wherever possible.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define WIDTH 16

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    int offset = 0;
    FILE *fp;
    int byte;
    char buffer[WIDTH] = ""; // This buffer will store the data read, essentially concatenating it

    if (argc < 2)
        return 1;

    if (fp = fopen(argv[1], "rb")) {
        for(;;) {
            byte = fgetc(fp); // get the next byte

            if (byte == EOF) { // did we read over the end of the file?
                if (offset % WIDTH)
                    printf("%*s %*.*s", 3 * (WIDTH - offset % WIDTH), "", offset % WIDTH, offset % WIDTH, buffer);
                else
                    printf("\n");
                return 0;
            }

            if (offset % WIDTH == 0) { // should we print the offset?
                if (offset)
                    printf(" %*.*s", WIDTH, WIDTH, buffer); // print the char representation of the last line
                printf("\n0x%08x", offset);
            }

            // print the hex representation of the current byte
            printf(" %02x", byte);

            // add printable characters to our buffer
            if (byte >= ' ')
                buffer[offset % WIDTH] = byte;
            else
                buffer[offset % WIDTH] = '.';

            // move the offset
            ++offset;
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Once compiled, pass any file as the first parameter to view its contents (shouldn't be too big to not break formatting).

Comment: Is there any check I can make to see if the value read from the file is '\0'?

Comment: @user2220232 Don't even start trying to read strings if all you want is reading single characters: `char byte = fgetc(yourhandle);` The operating system will buffer the file for you, so there shouldn't be any significant performance impact.

Comment: BTW, you said printf("%s\n", output); will print Hello. Why then in my output the null character i.e. ^@ is getting printed on giving printf("%c",char1); ?

Comment: fgetc is not suited for my job since I'm not just working with ASCII but byte values.

Comment: @user2220232 Because you're printing the actual character representation (using `%c` rather than `%s`). That's exactly the whole "interpret it as a string or as raw data".

Comment: @user2220232 `fgetc()` will return you the next byte from the file. It doesn't care whether it's ASCII, ANSI, BCD or whatever. :)

Comment: Even if I get it using fgetc, how do I concatenate it?

Comment: @user2220232 That really depends on what you want to do with it. You can just assign the elements of a `char` array (i.e. `char[]`) or whatever you want. I'm adding a simple hex editor style file viewer example to my answer, which might give you some ideas.

Comment: Thanks. This gives me some ideas about how to achieve what I want.

Answer (score 1):

C strings are null-terminated. If your input data can contain null bytes, you cannot use the string functions safely. Instead, consider just allocating a large-enough buffer (or dynamically resizing it as needed) and write each incoming byte to the right place in that buffer.